# Duplicate of Existing UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, copy

## h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *itemsContainer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *itemsContainerDefaults;
```

## m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.itemsContainerDefaults = [self.itemsContainer copy]; // breaks here
}
```

## console

```
2013-02-27 19:09:07.585 Test App[2038:907] -[UIScrollView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcde60
2013-02-27 19:09:07.586 Test App[2038:907] Uncaught exception: -[UIScrollView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcde60
2013-02-27 19:09:07.601 Test App[2038:907] Stack trace: ( ... )
```

I'm trying to copy `itemsContainer` to `itemsContainerDefaults` but I'm getting the error in the log. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call -copy on an object, it must conform to NSCopying. UIScrollView does not.

I think what you want to achieve has a better approach. But I'm not certain what you want to achieve. You want to make a visual copy of the scrollview? Why not just make a new scrollview that uses the same datasource as the first scrollview?

Comment: Good question. Essentially I just want a copy of all the scroll view's properties for later user (won't be visual ever).